# possible javascript exploits from exposed link?

Tags: javascript, exploit

On a page from a website (one of ours) I can enter in the url the following code:

```
javascript:createNewWindow('Something', 100, 100, 'Text')
```

Is there a way someone can exploit this?

```
function createNewWindow(url, widthIn, heightIn, title) 
        {
            var strOptions='toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=' + widthIn + ',height=' + heightIn;
            var newWin = open( url,title,strOptions ); 
            newWin.focus();
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, without an attacker knowing the source of createNewWindow?  Because the attacker will be able to read the source.

Comment: Good point.  I guess they could read it because it is downloaded to their machine.

Comment: Please clarify: can you (as an attacker) control only the parameters to createNewWindow or can you in fact enter arbitrary code after "javascript:"?

Comment: Cd-MaN - I added the code, so I think that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that code, the createNewWindow() script isn't any more vulnerable than the raw javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The function createNewWindow() has exactly the same vulnerabilities as window.open(). You probably don't need to be concerned about that.

If your comment about adding the code means that you were able to submit

```
javascript:createNewWindow('Something', 100, 100, 'Text')
```

in a form input (or as a query string parameter) and have it show up in the rendered HTML, then your application is indeed very vulnerable to several types of attacks, but not due to the createNewWindow() function. In that case, the problem would be rendering unchecked data from the browser.

Comment: There is no vulnerability in createNewWindow.  You have post some evidence.

Answer (score 1):

That will be not unsafe itself, you need to take care in the other parts of the application to prevent exploits. Be sure to validate all the information that becomes from the browser, your database, an external service, an anything else that you do not control.

Learning about Cross-Site-Scripting (aka XSS or CSS) will help you understand the risks of that code.

Answer (score 0):

In general javascript running on your site is not the source of vulnerabilities. You should be worrying about the server side of the application.

However!  You can introduce vulnerabilities into your site using javascript.  Its called [DOM Based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  The code you posted isn't vulnerable to DOM Based XSS.